# Automatic login after password reset?

Tags: security, web-applications, user-interface, passwords, usability

I'm working on a new password reset workflow on a website, and i am wondering if there are any best practices on the topic of logging in after a password reset.  Once the new password has been entered by the user, should they need to click login and enter their username and new password or be automatically logged in?  Personally I prefer them to log in after resetting the password so that their browser has a chance to update its saved passwords.  Automatic login just seems insecure to me.  Are there any other thoughts on the subject?

Comment: @subt13: Why does the language matter??

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - I meant to say what server-side technology (e.g. asp.net).  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @subt13: Same question: Why does the technology matter? This is not technology-specific at all.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark - because a framework/technology like asp.net already has user/password management built-in (membership providers), in which case there is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @subt13: I see your point. Still, he didn't ask about how to implement this, so the question as it stands is technology-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I'd recommend having one log-in entry point to your application. Although this additional log-in creates a burden on the user.

I'd say the benefits overcome this:

- Easy to track log-in activities
- If you want to apply some log-in rules like CAPTCHA, you will apply them in log-in page only.
- Browsers password management can identify the password entered only in log-in.